# Merging row content of text files in c#

Tags: c#, text, merge, rows

I have a two huge text files whose format is as below.

**File 1:**

ID1,20
ID2,20
ID3,30

**File 2:**

ID3,75
ID1,84
ID2,70

Both these files contain more than 200,000 rows. I need to read both the files and create a third file in this format:

**File 3:**

ID1,20,84
ID2,20,70
ID3,30,75

ID can be any string that user inputs. Third file should be created by matching the ID in rows of file 1 to the id in rows of file 2. I have written a code but it takes a lot of time to generate File 3. The task at hand deals with parallelization, so I want the code to save me as much time as possible. Please suggest a faster and more efficient way to deal with this problem.

**(Here is the code that I used)**

```
public void positionCure(string afile,string bfile,string dfile)
    {
        string alphaFilePath = afile;

        List<string> alphaFileContent = new List<string>();

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(alphaFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        using(StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            while(!rdr.EndOfStream)
            {
                alphaFileContent.Add(rdr.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        string betaFilePath = bfile;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(betaFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {

            while(! rdr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] betaFileLine = rdr.ReadLine().Split(Convert.ToChar(","));

                foreach (string alphaline in alphaFileContent)
                {
                        string[] alphaFileLine = alphaline.Split(Convert.ToChar(","));

                        if (alphaFileLine[0].Equals(betaFileLine[0].ToString()))
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", betaFileLine[0], betaFileLine[1], alphaline.Substring(alphaline.IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(","))+1)));
                        }

                }
            }


           }

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dfile, FileMode.Create))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            writer.Write(sb.ToString());
        }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Are your rows in file1 sorted by Id?

Comment: RedFilter's code worked brilliantly... it is fast as well as efficient..

Comment: @Sabi: Then you should consider to accept it (or another).

Comment: Apparently there is a little issue with the code. I have asked @RedFilter to help me resolve it... will accept is as soon as we resolve the issue... thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
string[] files = new string[] { @"c:\temp\file1.txt", @"c:\temp\file2.txt" };
var hash = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string[] fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    foreach (string line in fileContents)
    {
        string[] a = line.Split(',');
        if (!hash.Keys.Contains(a[0]))
            hash[a[0]] = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        hash[a[0]][a[1]] = true;
    }
}
foreach (var key in hash.Keys)
    Console.WriteLine(key + "," + string.Join(",", hash[key].Keys.ToArray()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. It worked pretty fast. Never thought of using the dictionary. Thanks again.

Comment: I did some thoroug testing and it seems that some of the rows in result doesnt have both the numbers. They just contain ID and one number and not the other... It would be great If I could get rid of such rows without having to read the result file again... an ideas.. thanks...

Comment: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/wcxhXGzjyT/file1.txt.html                       http://www.fileswap.com/dl/dfjr8PICue/file2.txt.html                           http://www.fileswap.com/dl/ZZL3xcaCMw/file3.txt.html

Comment: Also, you have duplicate values for the IDs in your files, do you want to keep those or remove them? E.g., `0BIOX:142:863,64,26,26`

Comment: i want to remove the duplicate values cos that will cause a problem when i store them in my database...

Comment: You haven't told me what ID doesn't have all of the numbers yet.

Comment: actually all the IDs that should have both numbers, have all the numbers... there are additional IDs that should not have both the numbers and therefore should not be included in the result file... these are the IDs I want to remove...

Comment: I'm not following you, but I updated the code above to remove duplicate values per ID.

Comment: Thanks for the update.. and I apologize for confusing things... Let me rephrase my question... if you see some rows in file3 that are like ID,NUMBER1 BUT DONT CONTAIN NUMBER 2... i dont want those rows... Sorry for making things complicated... :-)

Comment: for example you can find 0BIOX:104:452 in file 2 but not in file 1 but it is included as a result in file 3...

Comment: I'm going to leave that as an exercise for you. My code contains all the necessary concepts for you to tweak as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a `Dictionary`:

```
var combined = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// loop through each of the rows in the first file, and the second file, 
while (going through each of the files)
{    
    string id;
    string number;
    //and after splitting the line into the two variables:
    if (combined.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        combined[id] = combined[id] + "," + number; // or do something else, this is just an example
        // changing it from a Dictionary<string, string> to a Dictionary<string, List<string>> might be more performant, especially if you have a bunch of files you want to do this do, but it also might not be necessary.
    }
    else
    {
        combined[id] = number;
    }
}

// you can then run through the file and output it.

foreach (var pair in combined)
{
    file.Write(pair.Key);
    file.Write(",");
    file.Writeline(pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of good solutions here. Here is another simple one:

Grab the contents into a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> LoadFile(string path)
        {
            string line;
            Dictionary<string, string> vals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] parts = line.Split(',');
                    vals.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
                }
            }
            return vals;
        }
```

Then in your program, Load each file and merge

```
Dictionary<string, string> fileAValues = LoadFile(@"C:\Temp\FileA.txt");
Dictionary<string, string> fileBValues = LoadFile(@"C:\Temp\FileB.txt");

            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\FileC.txt"))
            {
                foreach (string key in fileAValues.Keys)
                {
                    if (fileBValues.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        string combined = key + "," + 

                          String.Join(",", fileAValues[key].ToString(),
                        fileBValues[key].ToString());  
                        sr.WriteLine(combined);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested in the VB.NET version(i'm always too slow with C#), so for the sake of completeness. I'm also using a Dictionary approach.

```
Dim dic1 As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
Dim file1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\File1.txt")
For Each l In file1
    Dim cols = l.Split(","c)
    If cols.Any Then
        Dim key = cols(0)
        If Not dic1.ContainsKey(key) Then
            Dim values = (From col In cols Skip (1)).ToList
            dic1.Add(key, values)
        End If
    End If
Next

Dim file2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\File2.txt")
For Each l In file2
    Dim cols = l.Split(","c)
    If cols.Any Then
        Dim key = cols(0)
        If dic1.ContainsKey(key) Then
            ' append '
            Dim values = (From col In cols Skip (1)).ToList
            dic1(key).AddRange(values)
        Else
            Dim values = (From col In cols Skip (1)).ToList
            dic1.Add(key, values)
        End If
    End If
Next

Using writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Temp\File3.txt")
    For Each entry In dic1
        writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1}", entry.Key, String.Join(",", entry.Value)))
    Next
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

By structuring this as a LINQ query, you can take advantage of the [AsParallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413602.aspx) method to execute it on multiple threads. This will drastically improve the performance of your algorithm, given that you have so much data.

First, we need to get a bit more structured. We can model the values you are using:

```
public class InputLine
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class OutputLine
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Value1 { get; set; }

    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

We can also define the producers and consumers of those values:

```
public class InputFile
{
    private readonly string _path;

    public InputFile(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public IEnumerable<InputLine> GetLines()
    {
        return
            from line in File.ReadAllLines(_path)
            let parts = line.Split(',')
            select new InputLine { Id = parts[0], Value = parts[1] };
    }
}

public class OutputFile
{
    private readonly string _path;

    public OutputFile(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public void WriteLines(IEnumerable<OutputLine> lines)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(_path, lines.Select(line => String.Join(",", line.Id, line.Value1, line.Value2)));
    }
}
```

Now we have the ingredients to write a query that ties it all together. There are two key aspects of this query:

1. Use the `.AsParallel()` extension method to execute it in parallel
2. Use the `join` operator to correlate the keys between the two input files

We just need the two input files and the output file:

```
public void WriteResults(InputFile file1, InputFile file2, OutputFile resultFile)
{
    var resultLines =
        from file1Line in file1.GetLines().AsParallel()
        join file2Line in file2.GetLines() on file1Line.Id equals file2Line.Id
        select new OutputLine
        {
            Id = file1Line.Id,
            Value1 = file1Line.Value,
            Value2 = file2Line.Value
        };

    resultFile.WriteLines(resultLines);
}
```

The `join` operator uses a similar approach to the dictionary behind-the-scenes, and you will also get the benefit of the correlation being done on multiple threads.